# Rmi, program is not ending?

Tags: java, rmi

Hi I have a class that is a remote object and I implemented methods.
Then I just wanted to test it in my local. So I added a main method on it. 
Then in main, I called runtUtilApp method , that just executes notepad, after some sleep I finish the working of notepad and I called stop method. After the all execution I wait program to finish execution. But it is still working and not ending.

What is the reason of this ?
I am thinking wrong ?

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.*;



public class ClientImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Remote{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 227L;
    private Process proc;

/**
 * constructor
 */
public ClientImp() throws RemoteException {
    super();
}


public boolean runApp() throws RemoteException {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        proc = rt.exec("notepad");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


public boolean stopCurrentUtilApp() throws RemoteException {
    proc.destroy();
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     client;
    try {
        ClientImp client = new ClientImp();
        client.runUtilApp();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        client.stopCurrentUtilApp();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your class extends `UnicastRemoteObject`, which means that when you create a new instance of your class, the `UnicastRemoteObject` constructor is called, which exports this object as an RMI server object, which cause a non-daemon RMI thread to start.

Call `System.exit()` to exit from the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

(I know this is a old question, but as it is referenced by many other RMI related questions I want to complete / extend the answer that was already given)

As already stated, the JVM is not exiting because a non-daemon RMI thread is still executing. This thread started to execute when the constructor of UnicastRemoteObject has been executed.

This constructor itself calls the static method `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, ...)` which is starting the RMI thread.

To end the thread, one could either call `System.exit()` or unexport the Object using `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(everyObjectThatHasBeenExported)`. The later has the advantage of not shuting down the JVM.

This is usefull in case you are building a restartable server / network service.
In this case not calling `unexportObject` on old (no more used) objects clutters the rmi thread. Moreover, I assume the exportedObject won't get removed by garbage collection because the rmi thread is still holding a reference on it.